MariaDB Rank Query
I am very new to PHP and SQL and building a project for hockey statistics.
For this page, I am looking to create a SQL query to rank hockey leaders based on goals scored. I am trying to take a table in my database with Team Id, and Goals For where the teams have a League Id = 0 and RANK the Goals For column.
I have tried the following query with no luck.
SELECT
`League Id`, `Team Id`, `Goals For`,
    RANK () OVER (ORDER BY `Goals For` DESC) `GF`
FROM
    `team_records`
    WHERE `League Id` = 0;

Everything I have come up with on the internet leads to a SQL error. How can I fix this? Any help is greatly appreciated.
The error message is:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'OVER (ORDER BY Goals For DESC) GF


Can you provide some sample data and expected output from provided data?

Hockey, yeah! Make it easy to assist you, provide a [mcve].

Also your mysql version will be important since window functions (RANK() OVER () in this case) are a newer-ish feature for that platform.

Sorry, all I am looking to do is get the ranks of each teams goals scored so that I can use PHP to show where a team ranks in Goals Scored in the league compared to the other teams in the league. Hope that makes sense.

What does "with no luck" mean? Are you getting an error? Or unexpected results? If unexpected results, in what way unexpected? Anyway, I'd add an ORDER BY Goals For DESC at the ent, so as to get the results sorted.

On a side note: I'd avoid column names that need quoting, as they can become a hassle. Just league_id, team_id, etc. and you can use the columns without those ugly backticks.

The code I entered below gave me the following error.
SQL query: Copy Documentation
SELECT
League Id, Team Id, Goals For,
RANK () OVER (ORDER BY Goals For DESC) GF
FROM
team_records
WHERE League Id = 0 LIMIT 0, 25
MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'OVER (ORDER BY Goals For DESC) GF

Put the details in the question, not a comment.

Why does MySQL say that you shall check the MariaDB manual? Sounds like you are using MariaDB and not MySQL.

Window functions were added in MariaDB 10.5. What version are you using?

I am using 10.4.28, I will look into updating it is just what came with my recent xampp download. Thanks.

Sorry @Barmar - wrong version - Window functions including RANK where actually added in 10.2.2, The Manual Corresponding to your MariaDB version is https://mariadb.com/kb/en/rank/. Do you see the differences in syntax compared to the Manual/Examples now?

you have an erroneous space between RANK and ()   https://dbfiddle.uk/D9FQV2Wd

@danblack I was googling for when window functions were added, not specifically RANK. I thought I found a page that said 10.5.0.

Try without the RANK to just return totals goals per team in the correct order without rank numbers. Then you can add the row/rank numbers on the front end with PHP:
SELECT
    `League Id`, `Team Id`, SUM(`Goals For`) `GF`
FROM  `team_records`
GROUP BY `League Id`, `Team Id`
ORDER BY SUM(`Goals For`) DESC
WHERE `League Id` = 0;

If this works, you probably need to upgrade your database, because it's a strong indication your database installation is too old for window functions. Worse, this also means it's old enough it no longer gets security patches. That's a big deal. It's important enough to even be worth the hassle of switching hosts.

Thank you, this pulls the data and ranks it, but how would I only output for instance the team with a Team Id =17 and show where their goals scored ranks in the league. I appreciate your help

To answer that question, start with my last paragraph.

The Syntax for RANK.
This requires:

No space after RANK and before ()
A ORDER BY clause

optional is:

A PARTITION BY clause

Based on other comments I assume you want to partition by the Team Id to RANK teams like:
SELECT
`League Id`, `Team Id`, `Goals For`,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY `Team Id` ORDER BY `Goals For` DESC) `GF`
FROM
    `team_records`
    WHERE `League Id` = 0
ORDER BY `League id`;

ref: https://dbfiddle.uk/JBgzYa2m

?  rank does not require a partition clause

Weird. A DBMS shouldn't care whether there are blanks between RANK and (). But you are right, MariaDB raises an error here. I'd consider this a bug. Other DBMS (MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.) are fine with a blank. You are wrong about the ORDER BY clause, though. This is mandatory for RANK in MariaDB.

Thank you, this answer at least got me in the right direction but all the ranks were showing as 1. I ended up trial and error and coming up with this query that worked.
SELECT League Id, Team Id, Goals For, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY League Id ORDER BY Goals For DESC) GF FROM team_records WHERE League Id = 0;

@ThorstenKettner MySQL (and I suspect also MariaDB) also prohibits a space after COUNT. If you have a space, it thinks it's a user-defined function rather than the built-in aggregation function.

from the other comment, I'm guessing they want rank in the league, not by team, but to only show the players on a team, so rank in a subquery
